# How to add a simple selector bar for a simple javascript slideshow?

Tags: javascript, css

I taught myself a little javascript over the past like 2 hours so bear with me.

I already have simple code in place for a very simple slideshow for a website. this is the javascript ('slide' class has an opacity of 0, 'current' class has an opacity of 1 so as to only show the 'current' one):

```
<script>

var Slideshow = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var Current = 0;
var Timer = setInterval(SlideMove,3000);

function SelectSlide(n) {
  SlideMove(Current = n);
}

function SlideMove(n) {
    Slideshow[Current].className = 'slide';
    Current = (Current+1)%Slideshow.length;
    Slideshow[Current].className = 'current slide';
}
</script>
```

Using CSS and HTML I made 5 little squares lined up under the slideshow, and I want for each square to correspond to one of the 5 photos I have in the slideshow, so that when it's clicked, the slideshow moves to that picture and continues the automatic slideshow loop from that point.

This is the HTML for the 5 squares (the class for each square is 'selector'):

```
<div id="selectors">
  <span class="selector" onclick="SelectSlide(0)"></span> 
  <span class="selector" onclick="SelectSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="selector" onclick="SelectSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="selector" onclick="SelectSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="selector" onclick="SelectSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

For the 'onclick' part, I thought that I was telling it to execute a new Javascript function I put in called 'SelectSlide(n)', which was this part of the code:

```
function SelectSlide(n) {
  SlideMove(Current = n);
}
```

According to what I saw in a tutorial, I thought this would take the number of the slide required (n), and execute the SlideMove function with 'Current' being equal to 'n'. So, I thought it would simply make the 'Current' value the value that was being selected and it would simply begin the slideshow loop from that point, but it doesn't work at all. When I click one of the selector boxes, it shows the image that I want to select but it doesn't hide the previous one and the whole thing looks like a mess. And then the newly selected image will just randomly disappear.

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the algorithm for the automatic slide changing loop, and the fact that I'm not hiding the previous slide, but I don't know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

If this question seems too confusing or poorly written for any reason feel free to ask me to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Hide/Show using `display:none` with your own javascript code.

```js
var Slideshow = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var Current = 0;
var Timer = setInterval(SlideMove,3000);

function SelectSlide(n) {
  SlideMove(Current = n);
}

function SlideMove(n) {
    Slideshow[Current].className = 'slide';
    Current = (Current+1)%Slideshow.length;
    Slideshow[Current].className = 'current slide';
}
```

```css
.slide{
  height:100px;
  display:none;
  background-size:100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    color: red;
}
.current{
  display:block;
}/*
.slide:nth-child(even){
  background:red;
}
.slide:nth-child(odd){
  background:green;
}*/
```

```html
<div id="slides">
  <span class="slide current" onclick="SelectSlide(0)" style="background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');">0</span> 
  <span class="slide" onclick="SelectSlide(1)" style="background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=00ff00&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');">1</span> 
  <span class="slide" onclick="SelectSlide(2)" style="background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=0000ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');">2</span> 
  <span class="slide" onclick="SelectSlide(3)" style="background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=ffff00&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');">3</span>
  <span class="slide" onclick="SelectSlide(4)" style="background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=000000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373');">4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically you're saying I should just use display: none and display: block to show and hide, instead of using the opacity? If so, I tried that and I still have the exact same problem. It will show the picture that I select but the one that came before it stays in the background and eventually the picture just disappears and it starts glitching out.

Comment: In the above i have shown you the demo click `run code snippet` you can see it working